# Meaning of Shmuel 2:22:26

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, samuel-shmuel-book-of

> עִם־חָסִיד תִּתְחַסָּד עִם־גִּבּוֹר תָּמִים תִּתַּמָּם׃
>
> With a kind person, You are kind. With a person strong in innocence,
> You are innocent. [Shmuel 2:22:26](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.22.26?ven=The_Metsudah_Tanach_series,_Lakewood,_N.J&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en)

תָּמִים could also be translated as whole, or "wholehearted", or simple.

I would like to know how Hashem can act תָּמִים, or rather how could He *not* appear תָּמִים to someone?

I would like to know why the first (חָסִיד) isn't diluted (or perhaps concentrated?) with the word גִּבּוֹר?

Comment: I have a similar question about Tehillim 18:26.

Comment: Why don't you ask directly on the end of the verse?

Comment: There's also Bava Basra 123a and M'gilla 13b (אמרה ליה ומי שרי לצדיקי לסגויי ברמיותא אמר לה אין (שמואל ב כב, כז) עם נבר תתבר ועם עקש תתפל) that could be construed as interpreting verses 26 and 27 as guidance for human behavior as opposed to a description of HaShem's behavior (although the gemara could also be interpreted as viewing these verses as a description of HaShem's behavior that people should also emulate).